# How select the menu on refresh?

Tags: jquery

In my page when I scroll the menu is changed. But when I'm in contact section and refresh the page it select the home page but stays on contact section.

```
var lastId,
    topMenu = $(".menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,   
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),   
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){        
        var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;        
        var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
            if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
            return this;
        });         
        cur = cur[cur.length-1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";   
        if (lastId !== id) {
            lastId = id;            
            menuItems
                .parent().removeClass("active")
                .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
        }                   
    });
```

Comment: you want your menu also be in sync right ?

Comment: can you please elaborate little more.

Comment: When I'm in contact section and refresh the page, I say in contact section, but menu not, it activates the "Home" menu item. But I need to activate "Contact" item menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try capturing the menu details(current menu which is active) on a session variable before the page is refreshed  and while loading  of the page refer to the menu details from same session variable and update menu.

**Code to capture menu details on unload:**

```
$('body').on('beforeunload',function(){
    //update menu details on session
    $.session.set("actMenu", $("#menu div.active").text());
});
```

**Code to update menu details on load:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //update menu from session
    $("#menu div").each(function() {
         if((this).text()==$.session.get('actMenu'))
             $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Happy Coding :)